# docker untagged images with tag (using docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to build my images, but they seem untagged, even though they show a tag. What am I doing wrong?

**Example postgresql**

*docker-compose.yml file*

```
version: '2'

services:
  postgresql:
    build:
      context: ../../../builds/psql95EP_DJ
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image:
      tl_psql95ep_dj:2017.04.05
```

In my understanding `:2017.04.05` is the tag. And when using `docker images` I see

```
REPOSITORY                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
tl_nginx1118_dj                       2017.01.12          e8b509d66e98        12 hours ago        191 MB
tl_psql955ep_dj                       2017.01.12          0e75847db871        15 hours ago        275 MB
```

but when I delete the image I get the messages

```
Untagged: tl_psql955ep_dj:2017.01.12
Deleted: sha256:0e75847db871147054a6b....and so on...long number
```

**same example with the nginx above:**

*docker-compose.yml*

version: '2'

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ../../../builds/nx1118_DJ
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image:
      tl_nginx1118_dj:2017.01.12
```

Delete gives me

```
Untagged: tl_nginx1118_dj:2017.01.12
```

I think it should have a proper tag, the way I do it:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Thanks!

Comment: "Untagged: tl_psql955ep_dj:2017.01.12" is a log message from docker. It means that it removed the tag from the image (untagged it). The next log message states that the image was deleted. Everything seems to be working as supposed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that @herm is right and untagged is the right procedure.

strange, I remember having images that didn's state untagged.....but cannot reproduce it anymore even with an official image

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

then check tag, showing 14.04 and when you do

```
docker rmi <id>
```

it also states untagged. Must have done something differently. Thanks